# PSQLException catching in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, exception

I'm using postgresql jdbc driver and there is the class `PSQLException` inherited from `SQLException`. What should I better catch `SQLException` or `PSQLException`?

Comment: it is related to more clearer exception message. you can use both one by one if you are not sure!!

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to catch the exception, so that your method will handle the exception and will not need to declare the `SQLException` in its `throws` clause, then you will need to catch the `SQLException`. This is because the JDBC API declares to throw SQL Exceptions.

Most of the `PSQLExceptions` will we anyway wrapped inside the more general `SQLException`, so to access them, you might use something like the following:

```
public static <T> T unwrapCause(Class<T> clazz, Throwable e) {
    while (!clazz.isInstance(e) && e.getCause() != null && e != e.getCause()) {
        e = e.getCause();
    }
    return clazz.isInstance(e) ? clazz.cast(e) : null;
}
```

then in your code you would get the `PSQLException` like this:

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
   PSQLException psqle = unwrapCause(PSQLException.class, e);
   if (psqle != null) {
       ... // handling of the PostgreSQL specific exception
   }
}
```